# Solution of this Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was studying the equation of motion in a problem, and I ended up with this differential equation

$$\frac{1}{2}m\dot u^2  + 2ku^2 - 4Eu = -\frac{2p^2}{m}$$

Where $k, m, E, p$ are constants.

Do you have some hint for helping me to solve this? The presence of both $\dot u^2$ and $u^2$ avoids me to use the usual methods.

By the way, Mathematica gave me a really simple solution in terms of sines, for the homogeneous. Then for the particular solution there are lots of exponentials.

Initial conditions are not given, but I suppose they would be for sure

$$u(0) = 0 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \dot u(0) = 0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ODE is equivalent to

$$\dot{u}^2 = au^2 + bu + c,$$

where I have assumed $m \neq 0$ and $a = - \frac{4k}{m},\ b = \frac{8E}{m}, \ c = -\frac{4p^2}{m^2}$. Additionally, note that your initial conditions imply that $c = 0$. We now differentiate the ODE and get

$$2\dot{u}\ddot{u} = 2au \dot{u} + b \dot{u}.$$

Clearly $\dot{u} = 0$ is a solution, but using the initial values, from this case we only get the trivial solution. So after cancelling $\dot{u}$, we get

$$\ddot{u} - au = \frac{b}{2},$$
which is a second order inhomogeneous linear ODE. We immediately see that 
$$u_{\text{p}} \equiv - \frac{b}{2a}$$
is a particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation (whenever $a \neq 0$), so we know look at the associated homogenous equation $\ddot{u} - au = 0$. The characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2 - a = 0$, which has the zeros $\pm \sqrt{a}$. We now distinguish some cases:

- **Case $a > 0$:**

  The general solution is

  \begin{align}u &= C_1 \mathrm e^{\sqrt{a}t} + C_2 \mathrm e^{-\sqrt{a}t} -  \frac{b}{2a}, \end{align}

  whereby $C_1, C_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.
  Plugging in the initial values leads to $C_1 = C_2 = - \frac{b}{4a}$, so the solution of the IVP is

  $$u_{\text{ivp}} = - \frac{b}{2a} \big(\cosh(\sqrt{a}t) - 1 \big ).$$
- **Case $a = 0$:**

  The second order ODE simplifies to $\ddot{u} = \frac{b}{2}$. After integrating twice and using the initial values, the solution is

$$u_{\text{ivp}} = \frac{b}{4}t^2.$$

- **Case $a < 0$:**

  The roots of the polynomial are $\pm \sqrt{a} = \pm \mathrm i \sqrt{-a}$. Then the general solution is

  $$u = C_1 \sin(\sqrt{-a} t) + C_2 \cos(\sqrt{-a}t) - \frac{b}{2a}.$$
  with real constants $C_1, C_2$. The initial values lead us to $(C_1, C_2)     = (0, \frac{b}{2a})$, so the final solution is

$$u_{\text{ivp}} = \frac{b}{2a} \big ( \cos(\sqrt{-at}) - 1 \big).$$

Comment: Since the sign of $a= - \frac{4k}{m}$ is unknown to us (as sign of $m$ and $k$ is unknown), so for concluding general solution you have to discuss the three cases for $a \gt = \lt 0$.

Comment: You have to mention that  $2\dot{u}\ddot{u} = 2au \dot{u} + b \dot{u} \implies \dot{u}(\ddot{u} - 2au - b)=0 \implies $ either $\dot{u}=0$, or $\ddot{u} - 2au - b=0$. Using the given condition from $\dot{u}=0$ we get nothing but the trivial solution, so we discard this  case.

Comment: @nmasanta You're right. I will extend my answer later.

Comment: Thank you for this. I may say, for completeness, that $m > 0$ always!

Comment: Thank you so much! The trick was to differentiate and I did not think about haha! Great lesson for me!